# Difficulty using Promises with a REST API that returns data in pages

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create a function that will retrieve all records from a REST API that uses paging.  The API returns `204 No Content` when all of the records have been returned.

I'm using Promises to manage the async process.

The problem is that I'm having difficulty passing the `statusCode` that is returned from to the do-while loop.

```
exports.get_workers = async (access_token, certificate, private_key) => {

    let page = 0
    let pageSize = 2
    let statusCode = 204  // No Content

    var promises = []

    do {

        promises.push( 

            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                const options = {
                    hostname: 'accounts.adp.com',
                    path: `/hr/v2/workers?$top=${pageSize}&$skip=${ page * pageSize }`,
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json;masked=false',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
                    },
                    cert: certificate,
                    key: private_key,
                };

                const req = require('https').request(options, (res) => {

                    // attempt to set variable that can be used in the do/while loop
                    statusCode = res.statusCode

                    if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                        reject(new Error(res.statusCode))
                    }
        
                    var body = [];
        
                    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                        body.push(chunk);
                    });
        
                    res.on('end', function() {
                        body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());

                        // statusCode = res.statusCode

                        // {
                        //     "workers": [{}...{}],
                        //     "meta": null,
                        //     "confirmMessage": null
                        // }
                        resolve(body.workers);
                    });
        
                });

                req.on('error', (e) => {
                    reject(e.message);
                });
            
                req.end();

            })
        
        )

        page += 1

    // loop until API returns a 204
    } while ( statusCode == 200 );

    return Promise.all(promises)

}
```

Is there a simple fix to scoping issue related to `statusCode`?

Another challenge is that the function returns an array of arrays of records:

```js
[
  [{worker},{worker},...],
  [{worker},{worker},...]
]
```

I'd prefer it to be:

```js
[
  {worker},{worker},{worker},{worker},...
]
```

Currently, I handle this in the calling code:

```js
const workers = await require("./workers").get_workers(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN, CERTIFICATE, PRIVATE_KEY)

workers.flat().forEach(w => {
    console.log(w.person.legalName.formattedName)
});
```

But I'd rather have this done by the function.

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: "Another challenge is that" — Please focus on a single problem at a time.

Comment: "I'm having difficulty passing the statusCode" — What do you mean by **the** status code? You're calling `request` in a loop. Each response is going to have its own status code.

Comment: `require('https').request` — you'll probably find things easier if you use a promise away HTTP API (like `fetch` which is built into modern Node.js versions, or Axios which is a popular module available on NPM).

Comment: `// loop until API returns a 204` — You need either recursion (and not a while loop) or `await`.

Comment: Obviously, `req.statusCode` won't be visible to the `while` check.  I created a variable, `statusCode`, with a different scope that would be visible to the `while` check.

Comment: — Which you never change because the loop runs forever preventing the callbacks which try to change the variable from running.